# Find out the view of the gesture has been set

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

In my `SecondViewController` I have a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell` where I have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and I want it to fail when `otherGestureRecognizer` is a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` from ViewController `FirstViewController`

The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of the the cell is set to self and I tried using `gestureRecognizer: shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer`:

```
override func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    let view = otherGestureRecognizer.view
    if let view as? FirstViewController.view { // Obviously doesn't work
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

The question is, how can I fail the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` of the `UITableViewCell` when a gesture has been recognized from FirstViewController?

Comment: Forget gesture recognizers for a moment. From a higher-level perspective, what are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: In my FirstViewController I have 2 views added from two other ViewControllers. When I use a `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` to pan the top view, the state will change to `open` and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` will be enabled so I can pan back the topview in its place. This works well, unless there's a `UITableViewCell` in the way. The cells have their own `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which prevents me from dragging back the topview.

Comment: If possible I'd like to solve it with the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate instead of using another delegate or `NSNotification`.

Comment: Okay, good explanation, thanks. I'm thinking about it... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem silly, but it seems to me your problem is purely one of identification: Is this gesture recognizer, `otherGestureRecognizer`, the particular gesture recognizer I'm worried about and am supposed to yield to? What occurs to me immediately are two choices:

- You have, as you rightly point out, its `view`. Are there no questions you can ask about this view that would help you identify it? Has it a distinguishing `backgroundColor` or any other feature that would help here? What about its class? Is it a plain vanilla UIView, or is it of some distinguishing class?
- You also have the UIPanGestureRecognizer itself. So a drop-dead simple solution, which is what I'd probably use, is to subclass UIPanGestureRecognizer: let's call the subclass MySpecialPanGestureRecognizer. This subclass has no special functionality, and no purpose except to act as an identifier! When you give the view its gesture recognizer, make that gesture recognizer a MySpecialPanGestureRecognizer. Now you can ask whether `otherGestureRecognizer is MySpecialPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: of course.. I've used so many subclasses of gestures and somehow I couldn't think of using one here. Nicely explained too, it was really easy to understand.

Comment: It would be nice if every class had an arbitrary built-in `name` property or other identifier, and in fact if you really wanted to you could inject such a property into Cocoa with an extension on NSObject. Some classes, such as CALayer, do let you do this, so yet another solution would be to use `setValue:forKey:` to assign this view's `layer` an identifier that you can later try to retrieve with `valueForKey:`. But just using a subclass as an identifier is simpler...

Comment: Finally for the sake of completeness I should point out that if you somehow already have a reference to this view, as `theView`, then you can ask whether `otherGestureRecognizer.view === theView` using the triple-equal operator.